# I'm trying to build my first assembly project in VS2019 to no avail

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

This is the assembly code I'm trying to run in VS2019:

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32 bits integer.
; Chapter 3  example

.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword

.code
main PROC
  mov eax, 5
  add eax, 6
  invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp

end main
```

When I press the F5 key I get the error message shown in the print screen below:

[image]

The code doesn't build. Note that I have selected within the project's `Build Dependencies > Build Customizations`, the option `masm`. What am I missing?

**Edit**

I found out what the problem was. I simply didn't update the file `main.asm` `Properties > Microsoft Macro Assembler > Item type` to `Microsoft Macro Assembler`. The immediate question that came to my mind was: why doesn't this `Item type` come with this (correct) setting, given that I had already selected in the project's `Build Dependencies > Build Customizations`, the option `masm`?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem stems from missing include files and libraries. You are advertising the external function `ExitProcess` with

```
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword
```

but do not include the corresponding header file (maybe "windows.inc" from hutch/MASM32) and are probably not linking the associated library file (some `.lib`).

Therefore the output of the assembler and linker is not present...
because the files are not produced due to errors...
giving you the error you are experiencing...

> File not found

Without knowing more of the development environment you are using, it's hard to tell what you should do in this case. The [MASM32 SDK](http://masm32.com/) by Hutch in combination with Iczelion's ASM tutorials([Download](https://forum.tuts4you.com/files/file/1746-iczelions-win32-assembly-tutorials/)) were a good start for Win32 ASM development.

Comment: Well, the assembler is not even being invoked. That is, when I Clean and Build `Project1`, the message "Assembling AddTwo.asm" doesn't show in the Output window.

Comment: I believe you mean ml.exe and ml64.exe. They are both installed in my system.

Comment: See my **Edit** above.